# Call Objective-C Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

How would I call this method, `- (void)displayView:(UIView *)view arg:(UILabel *)label {
}` after a delay of .5 seconds?

I have tried `[self performSelector:@selector(displayView:) withObject:view afterDelay:.5];` but that only passes *view* as a parameter.

How do I pass two parameters to a method with a delay of .5 seconds?

Comment: This is not related to Xcode at all.

Comment: BTW, wrap the arguments into a dictionary, and boom, you have made 1 arg from N args.

Comment: @H2CO3 Sorry about that. Good point. I might try that. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a delayed block invocation:

Main thread:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self displayView:view arg:label];
});
```

Background thread:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self displayView:view arg:label];
});
```

Comment: AHHHH I spent a half hour trying to figure out the updated way to do this! Thanks a lot!

Comment: There's no notion of deprecation in the [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_get_current_queue) for iOS, btw.

Comment: @Regexident Then that's a documentation error.   `dispatch_get_current_queue()` is annotated `__OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_6,__MAC_10_9,__IPHONE_4_0,__IPHONE_6_0)
` in the header.

Answer (score -2):

```
- (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector
           withObject:(id)anObject  
           withObject:(id)anotherObject
```

From [**Apple Documentation**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(displayView:arg:)
           withObject:myView
           withObject:myLabel];
```

But I would really suggest you to go with **[GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)**:

Another option is **dispatch_after**, which will take a block and enqueue it at a certain time.

```
double delayInSeconds = 5.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);

dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){

    [self displayView:myView arg:myLabel];

});
```

One more way is using **[NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html)**:

```
myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
    target:self
    selector:@selector(displayViewWitharg:)
    userInfo:dict
    repeats:NO];

// where dict is NSDictioary with key-value pair, which contains your parameters which you want to pass.
```

And here whenever you require you can invalidate this timer to stop the process.

Hope this will help you

Comment: I tried `dispatch_after` a while ago and ran into a deprecation warning on `dispatch_get_main_queue();`. I believe. I don't know if the way you're doing it is right but I can try that. Thanks. :)

Comment: I have added 3 various examples to run a process on separate thread. You can choose any of those according to your feasibility.

Comment: @Mrunal `performSelector:withObject:withObject` doesn't run in a separate thread -- it's run loop based (see the documentation for `NSRunLoop` for further details). Also, it doesn't provide a way to specify the .5 second delay the OP requires. Your `NSTimer` example is misleading. `NSTimer` instances can't invoke methods with custom signatures; the signature must be `- (void)methodName:(NSTimer *)timer`.